# How do you extend types in GraphQL?

Tags: types, graphql

For example, a `Pet` is an `Animal` with an `owner` and `name`.

```
type Animal {
  species: String
}

type Pet extends Animal {
  owner: Owner
  name: String
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Inherit or Extend typeDefs in GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523384/how-to-inherit-or-extend-typedefs-in-graphql)

Answer (score 60):

Starting with the [June2018 stable version of the GraphQL spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Object-Extensions), an Object type can *extend* another Object type:

> Object type extensions are used to represent a type which has been extended from some original type. For example, this might be used to represent local data

In your example,

```
type Animal {
  species: String
}

extend type Animal {
  owner: Owner
  name: String
}
```

This isn't inheritance per se; you can only extend the base type, not create new types based on it. Note there is no name for the new type; the existing `Animal` type is extended.

The [graphql.org documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/) doesn't mention anything about `extend`, but the documentation is [admittedly lackluster](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1368) and being [transitioned](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/1368#issuecomment-478194469) from Facebook's ownership to the Linux Foundation.
The JavaScript reference implementation [doesn't fully support extensions](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/922#issuecomment-493724046), but since you've tagged your question [apollo-server](/questions/tagged/apollo-server), you can use [`graphql-tools`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema#extend-types), which [does](https://runkit.com/dandv/graphql-tools-extend):

```js
const { graphql } = require('graphql');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

const typeDefs = `
  type Person {
    name: String!
  }
  extend type Person {
    salary: Int
  }  
  type Query {
    person: Person
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    person: () => ({ name: "John Doe", salary: 1234 })
  }
}  

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

graphql(schema, '{ person {name salary} }').then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

For actual type inheritance, see the [graphql-s2s library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-s2s).

Comment: So, to be clear, extending a type is like pushing another value onto an existing array?  Just as you can either write `const foo = [1, 2];`, or you can write `const foo = [1]; foo.push(2);` ... you can write a type def, or you can write a type def and extend it later?  If so, why would anyone ever use `extend`? What's the value of splitting your definition of a type into two different places?

Comment: @machineghost: I agree it's a crippled / immature implementation. Some reasons for using it anyway are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948335/1269037).

Comment: so what's the point on doing this? I only think of a use case of extending imported or 3rd party schemas.

Answer (score 19):

Although you cannot create sub-classes / sub-types you can do a form of inheritance using interfaces: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces

Example from the link above:

```
interface Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
}
```

```
type Human implements Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  starships: [Starship]
  totalCredits: Int
}
 
type Droid implements Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  primaryFunction: String
}
```

When querying you can specify specific fields for different implementations

```
hero(episode: $ep) {
    name
    ... on Droid {
      primaryFunction
    }
    ... on Human {
      totalCredits
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you please fill in an example `...` for the query, please? I am slow :)

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not possible in GraphQL, however there is an experimental package out there that might be useful for this purpose.

https://github.com/Sydsvenskan/node-graphql-partials

See example:

```
partial LinkFields {
  links(
    rel: String
    type: String
  ): [Link]
}

partial DocumentFields using LinkFields {
  uuid: ID!

  # The document type, such as x-im/article
  type: String
  # If specified, then a list of the products to which this document's availability is limited
  products: [String]
  # The human readable name of the document, often used publicly to identify the document
  title: String

  # The specific path on the web page where this document is publicly available
  path: String

  # A single metadata block
  metaBlock(
    # The specific metadata block type to get
    type: String
  ): MetadataBlock
}

interface Document using DocumentFields {}

type AuthorDocument implements Document using DocumentFields {}
```

Which results in:

```
type AuthorDocument implements Document {
  links(
    rel: String
    type: String
  ): [Link]

  uuid: ID!

  # The document type, such as x-im/article
  type: String
  # If specified, then a list of the products to which this document's availability is limited
  products: [String]
  # The human readable name of the document, often used publicly to identify the document
  title: String

  # The specific path on the web page where this document is publicly available
  path: String

  # A single metadata block
  metaBlock(
    # The specific metadata block type to get
    type: String
  ): MetadataBlock
}
```

What you can also do, since these are just strings is to create some helper functions that modify the string and insert the necessary fields.

If you are intereseted in following the discussion on Github, you can have a look at the following issue.

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/703

Comment: You can use `extend type` and it's possbile.

Comment: Just came here to express how cool it is that my local newspaper is active in open source. 

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are right to mention this is not type extension in a specialization way.

Beware, the type extension seems to have two syntaxes. According to the [Apollo Federation specification](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federation-spec/), there is an *@extend* syntax supported by graphql-java.

In the Apollo documentation, the syntax seems to be:

`extend type Animal`

But according to the Federation specification, another syntax is also supported:

`type Animal @key(fields: "id") @extends`

Some frameworks seem to support only the `@` syntax.