# How to handle Runtime Polymorphism in Graphql- Java

Tags: polymorphism, graphql-java

I was wondering that how can we handle Runtime polymorphism in Graphql Schema file,

```
@Data
class Parent {
   String libraryName;
}

@Data
class Child extends Parent {
 String bookName;
}
```

Test class=>

```
class Test {
 String id;
 Child childObj;
}
```

Now in normal case Runtime polymorphism will happen and Test.Child will be initialized with Parent class object
i.e. Parent prnt = new Child();

e.g.
Schema.graphqls

```
type Test{
  id: String!
  childObj: Child    // Cant assign Parent object
}

// This doesn't work
type Child {
    bookName: String
    libraryName: String
}

type Parent {
    bookName: String
    libraryName: String
}
```

But in GraphQl Schema file how to mention it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you could define an [interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) that both the `Child` and `Parent` types implement. For example, maybe you'd name it `Member` and change the type of `Test.childObj` to `Member`:

```
interface Member {
  bookName: String
  libraryName: String
}

type Test {
  id: String!
  childObj: Member    
}

type Child implements Member {
    bookName: String
    libraryName: String
}

type Parent implements Member {
    bookName: String
    libraryName: String
}
```

Another option might be the `extend` feature but that doesn't seem to be widely available yet. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917863/how-do-you-extend-types-in-graphql) .

Comment: Although I cant really use interface , I wanted to extend class only, but for now can see it has a work around. Thank you